# boolean value retrieved fron sql as string

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I send a boolean variable to SQL database, But when i retrieve it it was a string.

**The Entered Data Code Is:**

```
database.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE tasks (id integer PRIMARY KEY ,isFinished BOOLEAN) ");
```

When i retrieve the data the run time type is String!

**the code is:**

```
  Future<bool> checkBoxValue({required int id})async{
    Database? _database = await _createDB();
    List<Map<String, Object?>> isFinished= await _database.rawQuery("SELECT isFinished from tasks where id = '$id'");
   Object? c= isFinished[0]['isFinished'] ;
   print("\n isFinished:${c.runtimeType} \n");
     return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can modify your source code like below code:

```
 database.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE tasks (id integer PRIMARY KEY ,isFinished BOOLEAN NOT NULL CHECK (isFinished IN (0, 1))) ");
```

it will be worked. thanks

Comment: please let me know. thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).